# Java to send file to network printer on linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, networking, printing

I am looking for option where I can send the file to network printer using JAVA running on weblogic/Linux OS.

I searched throughly on web but not able to find a proper solution.

So, I am able to send the file to printer IP using Socket, but in this case I am not able to set Page Size or Number of copies. Thus when printer receive file, it beeps and then user has to manually select page size at printer.

```
  Socket sock = new Socket("190.129.2.4", 9100);
  OutputStream  output=sock.getOutputStream();
  InputStream  reader = new FileInputStream("./STEST.pdf");
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(reader);
  output.write(bytes);
  sock.close();
} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tested Java printer API, but the Java API lookupservices require printer to be added on the machine, as it is the server machine I cannot add the printers to it (Admin restrictions).
I tested printer API on windows by adding the printer and it works, 
but i do not know how do I send files if the printer is not added.

I also have the network printer Q path `"\\HOSTNAME\RICOHAMP4002”`

**I need a solution, where I can send the files for printing to the network printer without adding the printer on the server machine.**

Help really appreciated as it is getting escalated on my end and need some working approach soon.

Comment: You may use IPP to print. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830114/cups4j-printing-multiple-copies     http://www.cups4j.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655297/print-to-specific-printer-ipp-uri-in-java